# Writing multiplie lines in a single file using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am in the middle of a batch file programming and i got stuck in this below script.

```
( 
IF EXIST h:\*.png del h:*.png 
IF EXIST h:\*.mov del h:*.mov 
) > file.txt
```

My intention is the script first finds png and mov format in a given drive (in this case h)and then if exists it deletes it. i want to write all process to a txt file (file.txt).

As this is a simple question i really don't want to ask in main SE. I tried first in chat (hello world room). But i didnt get any useful replay regarding it.

Advance thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you might try this:

```
@echo off &SETLOCAL
(
IF EXIST h:\*.png (
    DIR /b h:\*.png
    del h:\*.png
)
IF EXIST h:\*.mov (
    DIR /b h:\*.mov
    del h:\*.mov
)) > file.txt
TYPE file.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

No need for IF. A simple one liner will do, and it is easy to add additional extensions:

```
>file.txt (for %%X in (png mov) do 2>nul dir /b h:*.%%X && del h:*.%%X)
```

***EDIT***

Shoot, it can be made even simpler:

```
>file.txt dir /b h:*.png h:*.mov && del h:*.png h:*.mov
```

Or, if you want to specify the list only once:

```
set "list=h:*.png h:*.mov"
>file.txt dir /b %list% && del %list%
```